# SabreDAV for .NET?

Tags: .net, wcf, webdav, caldav

Is there a CardDAV/CalDAV server framework similar to SabreDAV available for .NET?

I have a WCF REST service written in C# and I'm wondering how hard would it be to expose my calendar and contacts data using CalDAV and CardDAV protocols.

So far I've only found SabreDAV. It seems to be excellent, but it's a PHP framework, so I would have to maintain a whole new codebase.

Is there any SabreDAV alternative for .Net?

Comment: I guess anyone who builds for .net have the problem of adding webdav to IIS. In php where sites run on dedicated hostings, etc, it's a bigger problem. Yet, a good question :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have a limited set of options because this is a fairly niche area for .NET developers. There is a company that supposedly has a WCF library with support for [WebDAV with WCF](http://dev.palantir.co.za/WebDAV), but it lacks the CalDAV support you are looking for. You probably don't want to go down a route with IIS' WebDAV support as it isn't really designed to support the extensions you need.